# Airflow - Not running CUDA and Torch

Tags: airflow, gunicorn, torch, pytorch-lightning

I'm getting the error:
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method

I wasn't able to find a way to run CUDA application using torch libraries in Airflow due Gunicorn method of managing the parent and child processes with fork instead spawn.
I'd like to know if there is a way to run an application using GPU inside Apache airflow DAG.

My dag code:

```
with DAG(
dag_id='dag_temp',
description='Dag temp',
start_date=datetime(2022, 8, 18),
catchup=False
) as dag:

   from transformers import AutoTokenizer, RobertaModel
   import torch
   @task()
   def load_models():
      device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu' # device = cuda

      tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
      model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
      model.to(device)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leobit/Development/mlfactory-pipeline/src/dags/med_reader_pipeline.py", line 34, in load_models
    model.to(device)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 1749, in to
    return super().to(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 989, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 641, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 641, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 641, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 664, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 987, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
  File "/home/leobit/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mlfactory-pipeline-LOOcmODM-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 217, in _lazy_init
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

I've tried:
Change configuration of execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter to True
Reduce workes in Gunicorn settings.
Set the torch.multiprocessing to spawn method:
`mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this error happens, but I solved it by removing `if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'` from:

```py
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
```